# ANT: Reg regexp for extracting contents between slashes in property regex

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I have the following strings as input for scheduler file

```
Z:\cnt_development\cnt\test\Test-cases-blr\v80-WM\scheduler\FRQ\AUTO\sml-hr454\SRISM.xml
Z:\cnt_development\cnt\test\Test-cases-blr\v80-WM\scheduler\FRQ\AUTO\sml-lr454\Swap_MUL.xml
Z:\cnt_development\cnt\test\Test-cases-blr\v80-WM\scheduler\FRQ\AUTO\sml-lr456\Swap_MU.xml
```

I need to extract the complete part from v80-WM

i.e The regex must be able to select the following string

```
v80-WM\scheduler\FRQ\AUTO\sml-hr454\SRISM.xml
v80-WM\scheduler\FRQ\AUTO\sml-lr454\Swap_MUL.xml
v80-WM\scheduler\FRQ\AUTO\sml-lr456\Swap_MU.xml
```

Currently I am using the following regex where the regex finds the last occurence of "Q" in the above string and trimming for there and using workardoung to construct the above mentioned results.

```
<echo message="runpART ... Scheduler File ${schedulerFile}"/>
    <propertyregex property="cfg.arg" input="${schedulerFile}" regexp="([^Q]*).xml"        select="\1"   casesensitive="false"/>
```

Need help in extracting string from "v80-WM....xml".

Some inputs will be helpful

Comment: What do you know about the scheduler?  Does it always start with v80?  Does it always exist in a test case directory?  Is the full directory always the same?  Is the directory in another Ant property?  The answers to this will allow creating a less hacky regexp.

Comment: Yes the scheduler always starts with v80. After v80-WM, the directory structure changes. The directory structure is recursively read from v80-wm.

Answer (score 0):

That's good.  The v80-WM gives you a fixed "starting point"

Using this as your regular expression should do it.
    ^.*(v80-WM.*)

What it means:

- ^.* match anything until you get to *the caret isn't really necessary, but I like making the reg exp more strict)
- v80-WM
  = .* then match the rest

The parens include the v80-WM name and everything that comes after so you don't have to reconstruct it.